# winsocket2 addrinfo declaraction

Tags: windows, pointers, winsock, variable-declaration

I am having a bit of trouble understanding an example on a Microsoft winsock2 tutorial.

Would

```
struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
                *ptr = NULL,
                hints;
```

Be the same as

```
struct addrinfo* result = NULL;
struct addrinfo* ptr = NULL;
struct addrinfo hints;
```

I assume this creates two pointers `result` and `ptr` to an object of type `addrinfo`, assigns them to NULL and creates an object of type `addrinfo` named `hints`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. This:

```
struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
                *ptr = NULL,
                hints;
```

And this:

```
struct addrinfo* result = NULL;
struct addrinfo* ptr = NULL;
struct addrinfo hints;
```

Represent the same thing.